# What is a realistic, real-world, maximum size for a SQLite database?

Tags: database, performance, sqlite

According to this article on [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html) it says that, while SQLite is limited to **140 terabytes**, a client/server RDBMS may work better:

> An SQLite database is limited in size to 140 terabytes (2<sup>47</sup> bytes, 128 tibibytes). And even if it could handle larger databases, SQLite stores the entire database in a single disk file and many filesystems limit the maximum size of files to something less than this. So if you are contemplating databases of this magnitude, you would do well to consider using a client/server database engine that spreads its content across multiple disk files, and perhaps across multiple volumes.

In general, I agree with this, but I was surprised to learn that SQLite's maximum limit was so high! In my experience I have used quite a few SQL Server databases in the size of ~30-100GB. I have also worked indirectly with much larger databases using Oracle, Postgres, or Cassandra. Of those, at least to my knowledge, none were approaching 140TB. I'm not a DBA, so this is what I would consider "large" from my direct experience.

I have only considered SQLite for situations where the database would be tiny; dozens of megabytes at most.

After reading this article I'm still not convinced to ever consider SQLite for anything that might require hundreds of gigabytes. But I am wondering if I have been underestimating its capabilities. What is a realistic max size limit for a SQLite database in real-world use?

Comment: I just think we typically have to consider the number of concurrent connections since large datasets are often assumbed to be consumed by multiple users. There is a way for you to test this on your own system isn't there?

Comment: For something like a database of archived transactions that pretty much never needs to be accessed, SQLite might be a great choice, and there's only going to be one user at a time (if any), and you don't have to have a whole DB server setup to support it. If you've got multiple concurrent users, on the other hand, you could easily run into problems with locking getting in the way long before you get even to a several-gig database.

Comment: Hooking http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/332069/24257

Comment: @MichaelKohne, A whole DB server setup? That's hardly irrelevant isn't it, since you can set up a new instance of MySQL in about 10 seconds. On a desktop too.

Comment: @Pacerier - yea, to install the software. Then you've got to assign DB roles, figure out how to integrate into your backup system, make sure that the backup system puts the DB server into the proper state at the start and end of backups, etc, etc. There's far more to setting up a db server than just installing the software. Further, it's one more service that you have to worry about from a network security standpoint, and one more thing that you have to keep up with patching. If you NEED a db service, by all means go for it, but it you don't need it, SQLite has a heck of a lot less overhead.

Comment: @JeffO With adeqate SATA cards, card slots, and a monster logical volume theoretically you could test it...

Comment: @leeand00 - Or you could rent space for a month.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The realistic limit (of the size of some Sqlite database) is the same as the realistic limit for a data file. And that limit depends a lot of your computer & system. On my current Linux desktop I cannot afford much bigger than a 350Gbyte file (because as a rule of thumb I avoid having one single file eating more than half a disk partition). BTW, that practical limit also impacts other SQL RDBMS like PostGreSQL or MariaDB (but most of these are keeping data in *several* files, which you  might keep on different file systems, and some of them are able to manage distributed data on remote machines...)

> After reading this article I'm still not convinced to ever consider SQLite for anything that might require hundreds of gigabytes

You are right and wrong.

You are right, because on today's computer (laptops & desktops, not supercomputers or datacenter servers), a hundred gigabyte is still a quite large disk space. So in practice, if you think of such a large database, you'll better imagine a real SQL server (à la PostGreSQL) in particular because you might want very probably remote access, effectively concurrent access and probably distributed data & tables.

You are (in principle, I never tried) wrong because very probably SQLite is capable (and sometimes tested) to deal with a database of several hundred gigabytes, assuming you have a filesystem capable of dealing with such a large file (and probably two of them at least).

I certainly would (sometimes) consider SQLite for databases of several dozens of gigabytes (and I did try once such a large `.sqlite` file, IIRC of 40Gbytes). On current (non-supercomputer) machines, I would hesitate having many hundred of gigabytes of SQLite database, simply because such a file is quite big by today's practice.

IIRC some hardware vendor selling specialized filesystems machines did spoke me once of a terabyte sqlite application (but I could be wrong).

Of course SQLite performance depends (like all SQL databases) *a lot* of the number and width of tables, their indexes, the SQL queries involved. And you don't want to have simultaneous access (by many different processes), and you should use transaction (by experience, even on an tiny SQLITE database of a few megabytes, you really want to wrap your e.g. thousand of insertion requests with `BEGIN TRANSACTION` & `END TRANSACTION`, not doing that is slowing down Sqlite by a large factor -more than 10x-).

And by personal experience, with suitable configuration and organization, SQLite is able to manage a database bigger than available RAM (so 30Gbytes is not a problem) - but you probably want the indexes to fit in RAM!

If you happen to code something for a "supercomputer" or a costly workstation (with e.g. 512Gbytes of RAM and 8Tbytes of disk and 512Gbyte of SSD) you certainly can have a terabyte Sqlite database. But you'll want to do that perhaps only if one (or very few) process(es) is accessing that database. If you have a dozen of processes accessing concurrently the same database, better install a real SQL RDBMS (à la MariaDB or PostGreSQL)

Also note that while the (binary) format of `.sqlite` database files is [documented](http://sqlite.org/formatchng.html) as being "portable", I much prefer to backup databases in SQL *textual* format (using `sqlite3 mydb.sqlite .dump > mydb.sql`). Then, I also need some additional disk space for that textual dump (and that lowers the realistic limit).

Usually Sqlite is not the bottleneck. But the disk might be.

PS. The same reasoning could be applied to large indexed files using [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/).

<sup>PPS. In my [expjs](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015/tree/expjs) branch (sept.2016) of my MELT monitor (GPLv3 free software, on github) I am [persisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29) the entire application heap in JSON inside a fresh Sqlite database. I've run tiny experiments with several millions objects (quite "large") without bad surprises. YMMV.</sup>

Comment: You could have stopped writing after the fourth paragraph.  But +1 anyway.

Comment: Maybe, but I was unpleasantly very surprised to notice that even on a fresh sqlite database of only a few megabytes, transactions are so important in practice (with only one single process accessing, actually writing, that new file).

Comment: That's certainly true for writes.  In practice, it's hard to imagine a SQLite database with sizes like the OP describes.  Postgresql would probably be a better choice, not for its size capabilities, but for the industrial-strength concurrency which SQLite does not have.

Comment: There are plenty of legit situations where you could have SQLite databases with huge file sizes. From the SQLite developers themselves: think of it less as a replacement for MySql, and more as a replacement for fopen. Writing some 3D cad software, and using SQLite databases to store data about objects, can be perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, Re "you probably want the indexes to fit in RAM", How do you set the indexes to fit in ram?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, A few hundred GB is nothing at all these days. Even a single high quality movie file can easily chomp up many GB.

Comment: @Pacerier: you might guess-estimate the required size of indexes (which is much smaller than the indexed data).

Comment: @Pacerier: Movies files and similar binary blobs are typically not stored in the database.  They are stored in the file system, and links to them are stored in the database.

Comment: If stackExchange had a "remind me" feature I'd tag this question for 20 years from now.  So we can all laugh at how great it is that we can use the sql-within-DNA jdbc engine to read 140 Terabytes of browser history from a single eyebrow hair.

Comment: @andrewlorien Sure you can, there is a bookmark icon under the vote icons